# t.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even after installing lots of plugins / cant debug error

Tags: qt, ubuntu, dependencies, qt5

On debug, my application works when I launch through qmake. But when I build a release and try to launch it, I get:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662135/6655884 so I tried

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGIN=1
./mybinary
```

but the same error appears. It won't tell me which plugins are missing.

Here's a part of the .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui widgets network xml xmlpatterns printsupport svg
```

I installed `libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev` and `libqt5xmlpatterns5` and `libqt5printsupport5` and `libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev` and `libqt5xmlpatterns5` and `libqt5svg5-dev` and `libqt5svg5`. Don't know what more I should install (tried to find libqt5-network but couldnt find it)

My other app which has

```
QT       += core gui widgets xml svg printsupport xmlpatterns
```

runs normally even in non debug mode.

**UPDATE:**

```
user@localhost:~/local/bin$ export QT_DEBUG_PLUGIN=1
user@localhost:~/local/bin$ ./seamlyme 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Aborted
```

**UPDATE:**

```
user@localhost:~/seamly2d$ /home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/home/user/Qt/Docs/Qt-5.12.6
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/libexec
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/home/user/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.12.6
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/home/user/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.12.6
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_HOST_DATA:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64
QT_HOST_BINS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:linux-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:linux-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:5.12.6
```

Comment: show full log after running  `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGIN=1
./mybinary`

Comment: @eyllanesc see the update

Comment: What is the output of `qmake -query`?

Comment: @eyllanesc updated