# Problem with running Qt5 GUI app in raspberry 4 (no desktop)

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, raspberry-pi4

I've installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32 bit(no desktop) on raspberry4 and all Qt5 dependencies for my qml app.
After building the code , when I run

```
./myproj
```

, I get error of :

```
 qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I don't know what should I do to run my GUI app in no desktop raspberry .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.' after fixup\_bundle macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362015/how-to-fix-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was)

Comment: I can get what I want using " ./myproj -platform eglfs" but I want to run it only with "./myproj"

Comment: Export an environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs`, this should be equivalent to your `-platform eglfs` command-line parameters